# Passing limit through integral

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ and $(X^{\varepsilon}_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ be  stochastic processes such that $X_t$ and $X_t^{\varepsilon}$ are both in $L^2$ for $t \in [0, T]$ and $X_t^{\varepsilon}\rightarrow X_t$ as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. Denote $V_t$ a random variable such that $V_t^\varepsilon := \frac{X_t^{\varepsilon} - X_t}{\varepsilon} - V_t$ uniformly converges to $0$ in $L^2$ as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$.
The aim is to prove the following limit:

$$
\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \mathbb{E} \int_{0}^{T} \int_{0}^{1} \partial_x f(t, X_t + \lambda \varepsilon (V_t^{\varepsilon} - V_t))\cdot (V_t^{\varepsilon} + V_t) d\lambda dt = \mathbb{E} \int_{0}^{T} \partial_x f(t, X_t) \cdot V_t dt.
$$

If $\partial_x f$ is uniformly bounded in $x$, then using dominated convergence theorem and uniformly convergence of $V_t^\varepsilon$ solves the problem.

But I was confused about the case where $\partial_x f$ is only linear growth in $x$, that is, $\partial_x f$ is bounded by $L(1+\vert x\vert)$. It seems that the only trouble is passing the limit through integral, but I don't know how to show that.

Comment: I think something has to be made  clear about $$\mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^T|V_t|^2dt\right)$$
Is this integral finite?

Comment: If yes, this question seems to be not hard.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Yes, it is finite. I think I know how to do this. Using linear growth in $x$ and Hölder's inequality, together with the uniform convergence of $V_t^{\varepsilon}$ yields that the first term of left hand tends to $0$. Similar arguments can be applied to the second term.

Comment: yeah, it’s the way it should be.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen But I attempted to use the uniformly integrable argument, which appears in the original text, to show this limit hold and I failed. Is there another way to use uniform integrability? As for the uniformly integrable argument mentioned in the original text, I think it should mean that convergence in probability and uniform integrability implies $L^1$ convergence.

Comment: I think you are right. However, in that case,  even proving  "the convergence in probability" is not trivial, noticing that we dealing with limits under many integrals.